# How to design a database to keep track of books my family owns?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am not necessarily looking for MySQL or PHP code. Rather I'm trying to get a concept of how to set everything up.

I want to create a database using MySQL (and using PHP to update it) of all the books my family owns. I want to set up different 'bookshelves' for each person in my family so we can see who has a certain book.

My first thought was to have a table for all the titles, authors, etc and have a field for user id to show who had the book. However, I might have a copy of Hunger Games and my grandmother might have a copy of Hunger Games. I want to be able to show it on both bookshelves. The only way my idea would work is if we had no duplicate books.

My next idea was to use a different table for each user and have a field that contains the book id for each book the user owns. I think this would work on a small scale but it does not seem like an efficient design. I am planning on making the database public for everyone in my town to use (thousands of people) once I get a stable website going so I want to start off with the right kind of design.

How should this be designed?

Comment: Lots of ways to do this, another solution would be one table for books and another for users, and a third books/users table that links each user with each book (one to one) - so if you and your grandmother had the same book, there would be two entries in the books/users, one with the book id and your user id, one with the book id and her user id

Comment: "My next idea was to use a different table for each user" no no, just have 1 table that has primary key for the users, and, have different tables (books etc..) that have a foreign key linking the tables together. The "Hunger Games" may appear twice inside your database, BUT will have different user_id's. Alternatively, have one table that stores all of the books and then have another table called "Copies" which links to the books and users. (User: "1", Book: "Hunger Games", Copies: "1" ... User "2", Book "Hunger Games", Copies "1" BUT make sure a foreign key links from "Copies" to "Users"

Comment: Out of interest, what are you using for your book id?  The ISBN?  Just wondering about issues with identity.  This isn't technically a database concern, but since your ids will be central to how you'll reconcile your data...

Comment: I will not be using the ISBN because I might eventually expand this to include movies and video games. Maybe UPC code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BOOK
--------
book_id
title
other_book_related_info

PERSON
-------
person_id
name
other_person_info

BOOK_PERSON
-------------
book_id
person_id
possibly-dates-when-this-person-owned-this-book
```

Comment: So in this example, BOOK_PERSON would be where I show which books everyone owns. I would have multiple rows with the same user id and I would have multiple user ids linked to the same book. Am I grasping the concept correctly? I am rather new to database design.

Comment: yes - there will be multiple entries here linking the people to all their books

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple solution i can think of:

> Book Table : List of all unique books
>
> User Books : contains the user id and the book id. multiple users can own the same title.
>
> Users      : List of users;

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty basic. Owner, book and author should be self explanatory. Add any additional fields to those tables you want. The bookshelf and book_authors are both cross reference tables so each book can have multiple owners and each book can have multiple authors.

```
**owner:**
owner_id
owner_name
...

**book:**
book_id
book_name
...

**author:**
author_id
author_name
...

**bookshelf:**
owner_id
book_id

**book_authors:**
book_id
author_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You might like to differentiate between ownership of the book and current possession, since people will doubtless be borrowing. So the tables of BOOK (best call it ITEM if you're going to expand to DVD's etc) and PERSON, and the ownership table BOOK/MEDIA_OWNER, might be usefully accompanied by an ITEM_LOAN table.

You might like to also allow grouping of sets of items so that multiple volumes of a book, or discs of a show season, can be identified individually. Books (and films etc) also come in series, so think about how to represent that as well.

By the way, it's a generally accepted rule that if an edition of a work changes by more than 20% between print runs then it is a new impression, but it is not always granted a new ISBN. Depends on the publisher. Also, the hierarchy for books is based on Work -< Edition -< Impression, and [these folks](http://www.editeur.org/) would be a good source of information of data structures relating to books.

Comment: A "series" field in the ITEM table should suffice, yes? It can go along with the genre, year, etc. +1 for this idea, I like it.

Comment: @KennyJohnson yes, although it could be useful to break it out into another table as you might want to indicate series order. The order might be publication based (although you'd get that from the publication date of the work) or what you might call the "internal timeline order" of the series (eg. in the Ender Series http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game_%28series%29)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
**** BOOK ***
book_id
book_title
book_desc
book_bought

*** USERS ***
user_id, 
name,
dateOfBirth

** Copies **
copy_id (PK)
user_id (FK)
book_id (FK)
NoOfCopies
```